# sed - Remove text that precedes two blank lines

Tags: linux, bash, perl, awk, sed

I need help removing a text that precedes two blank lines.

Can anyone help do this with SED?

Example: (my log file)
lines with: "%%%% Info | Date: ..."

Source:

```
%%%% Info | Date: (11-02-18)-Day=042 - %%%%

OLD: android-902 (11-02-18 02:30)

Wi-Fi up - USB (11-02-18 03:21:21)

%%%% - Info | Date: (12-02-18)-Day=043 - %%%%

Wi-Fi up - USB (12-02-18 07:17:02)

Smart Connected (12-02-18 10:19)

%%%% - Info | Date: (13-02-18)-Day=044 - %%%%


%%%% - Info | Date: (14-02-18)-Day=045 - %%%%


%%%% - Info | Date: (15-02-18)-Day=046 - %%%%


%%%% - Info | Date: (16-02-18)-Day=047 - %%%%

Wi-Fi up - USB (16-02-18 06:32:24)
```

Output:

```
%%%% Info | Date: (11-02-18)-Day=042 - %%%%

OLD: android-902 (07-02-18 02:30)

Wi-Fi up - USB (07-02-18 03:21:21)

%%%% - Info | Date: (12-02-18)-Day=043 - %%%%

Wi-Fi up - USB (12-02-18 07:17:02)

Smart Connected (12-02-18 10:19)

%%%% - Info | Date: (16-02-18)-Day=047 - %%%%

Wi-Fi up - USB (16-02-18 06:32:24)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Please show your code. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/).*

Comment: In your output, why is the penultimate non-blank line `%%%% - Info | Date: (16-02-18)-Day=047 - %%%%` and not `%%%% - Info | Date: (13-02-18)-Day=044 - %%%%`.  The latter has only one blank line before it; the one you show has two.

Comment: You're right, I made the mistake of editing.
A daily bookmark "%%%%" is preceded by two blank lines:
echo -e "\n\n\t%%%% - Info | Date: `date +"(%d-%m-%y)-Day=%j"` - %%%%" >> $LOG
A log event is preceded by only one line:
echo -e '\n'Wi-Fi up - USB `date +"(%d-%m-%y %T)"` >> $LOG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sed` is a very powerful tool, however it is not the best tool to use for multi-lines processing, just use the following `awk` solution for your task.

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{RS="%%%%[^%]+%%%%\n\n\n"}{printf "%s",$0}' input.log
%%%% Info | Date: (11-02-18)-Day=042 - %%%%

OLD: android-902 (11-02-18 02:30)

Wi-Fi up - USB (11-02-18 03:21:21)

%%%% - Info | Date: (12-02-18)-Day=043 - %%%%

Wi-Fi up - USB (12-02-18 07:17:02)

Smart Connected (12-02-18 10:19)

%%%% - Info | Date: (16-02-18)-Day=047 - %%%%

Wi-Fi up - USB (16-02-18 06:32:24)
```

Explanations:

`RS="%%%%[^%]+%%%%\n\n\n"` is the record separator that will be used by `awk` in order to find each record, as you use the default `ORS` those fields will just be removed from the output and replace by an `\n`

Comment: This is amazing, it worked fine in my log file deleting a series of empty records and making it easier to control them. Thank you very much.

Comment: @murilo.xd: great that it helped you, if you are satisfied with my answer could you put it as correct answer? Thanks